# How do I add a javascript alert to innerHTML at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

When a particular event happens that I listen out for - I want to populate the div 'divDynamicAdvert` with the javascript that calls my Google Ad code.

Huge thanks to "tenbits" for showing me that I need to be appending a script node like this:

```
function myEventHandler(evt)         //called when event is caught
{   
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = 'alert(1)';
  document.getElementById('divDynamicAdvert').appendChild(script);
}
```

This works great, but in place of the alert, I need to insert the Google Ads Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3286208413631803";
        /* Standard MPU */
        google_ad_slot = "8630273973";
        google_ad_width = 300;
        google_ad_height = 250;
        //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I've tried:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = 'google_ad_client = 'ca-pub-3286208413631803'; google_ad_slot = '8630273973'; google_ad_width = 300; google_ad_height = 250;';
document.getElementById('divDynamicAdvert').appendChild(script);

var script = document.createElement('script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"');
document.getElementById('divDynamicAdvert').appendChild(script);
```

I've tried escaping the slashes too, but no luck...  Can you guys help?

Comment: Hb you just call `alert()` in the JS logic where you're assigning the `innerHTML`?

Comment: Your advertisement will actually overwrite your page if you insert it that way.

Comment: Perhaps if you could tell what you are trying to achieve instead of how we could give you a better alternative.

Comment: Scripts added by innerHTML will not be interpreted. You need to use eval instead (before anyone say eval is evil, what he's trying to do is eval - don't just repeat a meme, understand the real issue - eval has many names: `document.createElement('script')`, `<script src="">`, `(Function(""))()` - they all mean "eval" but I see people proposing them with a straight face while saying eval is "evil")

Comment: I know - at the moment all it will do is fire an alert. It's just to prove it can be done.  I have a video player, when the video starts, it displays a companion MPU inside the div "divDynamicAdvert",  When the video stops playing, I capture the event and instead of firing an alert, I want it to insert my google ads script into the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @slebetman already said, `innerHTML` wont work. If you trying to evaluate script via DOM, and not `eval(code)`, etc - do this with `SCRIPT` Node:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = 'alert(1)';

document.getElementById('divDynamicAdvert').appendChild(script);
// actually it doesnt matter where you append it
```

**EDIT**:

In any case create a SCRIPT NODE, and then manipulate with it - add a script content to it **OR** add src attribute if you reference external source

```
var script;

// content
script = document.createElement('script')
script.textContent = 'alert(1)'
document.body.appendChild(script);

// google api source
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'ANY_URL';
// -> in this case, same as script.setAttribute('src', 'ANY_URL');

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Having some further questions, do not hesitate to ask in comments.

Comment: This is brilliant TenBits, Thanks - I've updated my question to reflect your input...